# When I click Shutdown in Ubuntu inside of VMware Player, nothing happens

Tags: ubuntu, vmware

I don't even get an error message, nor does anything freeze. All I can do is press `Escape` to get out of the Shutdown dialog and use VMware Player to forcably shut down Ubuntu.

When I use `sudo shutdown now`, the Ubuntu closing splash screen displays, then freezes, still requiring me to manually shutdown using VMware controls.

Specs:

- Ubuntu 12.04
- VMware Player 5.0.0
- Windows 7 Professional x64
- MacBook Pro 2009

I also posted this on the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12247038).

Comment: What happens when you run `sudo shutdown now` from a terminal screen?

Comment: @RandolphWest, the system stops at the shutdown splash screen, so I still have to press the VMware power off button.

Comment: Did you ever discover how to do a clean shutdown as I'm having this same issue now running the latest version of Ubuntu in VMWare on Windows 7?